# How to change the command text to procedure for sql query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using treeview with connectivity of sql server i am using only command text to select table records in the method. How to change the command text to procedure for this sql query:

```
com.CommandText = "select TN_ID from Treeview where TN_ValuePath='" + TN_Title.Parent.Value + "';";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: "select TN_ID from Treeview where TN_ValuePath='" + TN_Title.Parent.Value + "';";  I will ask about how to change select query to sql procedure